# Should I use "his" or "their" in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

> The image of a European dressed in **their / his** finery going out to gaze upon...

Should I use *their* or *his*?

In my opinion "their" is the correct pronoun because it refers to both men/women. Though, my SAT exam preparation book states "his" is correct because it refers back to *a European*, which is singular.

Why should I use "his" in the sentence above instead of "their"?

Comment: The SAT wants you to use *his*. Many people now use *their* in this context. See [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun ("his" versus "her" versus "their")?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The image of ***a*** European dressed in **his** finery going out to gaze upon...

In this particular case, you're talking about *just one European*: "dressed" is referred to *one* of them - no matter what his/her sex is: it's just *one person* and you should use a singular possessive adjective. You should have used *their* if the noun to which "dressed" is referred had been "European people" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I thought we could use "their" when we don't know the sex of a person. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Cesare The use of *his/her* is more common in this case in a colloquial context. As GoDucks pointed out, [*they* referred to a singular noun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) is not completely wrong, but it's highly criticised.

Comment: Can someone explain the reason of the negative vote to my answer?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I think it might have been because you completely dismiss the use of "singular they".  Given that [*singular they* has been used for hundreds of years and has gotten official approval](http://www.americandialect.org/2015-word-of-the-year-is-singular-they) (well, as close to "official" as there is in English, anyway), that might make the answer not entirely correct.

Comment: @stangdon Thanks for the explanation. I read somewhere that it is largely criticised, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2016/01/08/donald-trump-may-win-this-years-word-of-the-year/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to say with that sentence.

If you say "The image of a European in his finery" then I understand that you actually mean "The image of a male European"; similar for "her". When you use "their" the I understand that you mean "The image of a European, who could be either male or female...". So all three are correct, but with different meaning.

Using "his" for a single person who might be male or female seems confusing to me.